# How to make a text box validate during run time

Tags: jquery, html

I want when i focus into textbox if it is empty it should show "name is required" and if we type a single letter that message("name is required") should disappear.

```js
$("#name").focus(function() {
  var name = $("#name").val();
  if (name != "") {
    $("#name-error").text("");
  } else {
    $("#name-error").text("Name is required.");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Here is a text box in form for name in a form
<label>My Name:</label>
<input type="text" id="name" />
<span id="name-error">*</span>
```

Comment: consider using a form validation plugin such as `https://jqueryvalidation.org/`

Comment: take a look at `placeholder` attribute

Comment: use ``keydown`` or ``keyup``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.keyup` event handler ,

```js
$("#name").on('keyup focus',function() {
  var name = $("#name").val();
  if (name != "") {
    $("#name-error").text("");
  } else {
    $("#name-error").text("Name is required.");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>My Name:</label>
<input type="text" id="name" />
<span id="name-error">*</span>
```

Comment: what happens if i use keydown or keypress instead of keyup?

Comment: @KoteswaraRao its upto you basically. From your requirement I found that you need to check for users input so ideal was keyup. As soon as user done with providing input you trigger your checks.

Comment: @KoteswaraRao To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is fine here, one correction is required. You have to hide the error on user input like:

```
$("#name").keydown(function(){
    $("#name-error").text("");
});
```

But I suggest you to use jquery plugin like [Jquery Validation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/)